# Php DomDocument saveXML change tags closure standard

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I have to parse XML files that have some tags closed like this `<Test></Test>` and some others like this `<Test />`. I need to keep the tag style identical to the original file.

Is there a way to specify to DomDocument to keep the original closing style?

Example:

```
$example = <<<XML
<example>
    <selfClosed/>
    <empty></empty>
</example>
XML;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($example);
echo $dom->saveXML();
```

Outputs:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<example>
    <selfClosed/>
    <empty/>
</example>
```

I tried with `LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG` but it changes the way all tags are closed, it doesn't retain the original style:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($example);
echo $dom->saveXML(null, LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG);
```

Outputs:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<example>
    <selfClosed></selfClosed>
    <empty></empty>
</example>
```

Comment: It isn't possible with DOMDocument, try something with XMLReader.  "I need to keep the tag style identical to the original file": for what reason? XML aims to store structured datas, not to be beautiful!

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Tried also with XMLReader, I don't find a way to do this.
I must preserve tags closure cause was a request's specification

Comment: You will have to write your own parser/serializer. However a self closing tag has the same meaning as an empty one. If you client/spec requires a specific style it is broken.

Answer (score 0):

[XMLReader](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xmlreader.php) is not the most convenient parser but it provides [this information](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.xmlreader.php#xmlreader.props.isemptyelement):

```
$example = <<<XML
<example>
    <selfClosed/>
    <empty></empty>
</example>
XML;

$xmlReader = new XMLReader();
$xmlReader->xml($example);
while ($xmlReader->read()) {
    if ($xmlReader->nodeType === XMLReader::ELEMENT) {
        echo '<', $xmlReader->name, '> is ', $xmlReader->isEmptyElement ? 'empty' : 'not empty', PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/3p6vV#v8.2.4)